# Can one prove the poincare duality for projective scheme by proving it for projective space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology

It's well known the relationship between Poincare duality and Thom isomorphism（I mean cohomology purity $R^q i^! F=0$ if $q\neq c  $ ) $\quad $

$Rf_!Ri_!=R(f|_Z)_!$ where f is $P_k^n\rightarrow k$ and Z is a close subscheme of P,i the closed immersion so Verdier duality $R(f|_Z)^! \tilde {=}Ri^!Rf^!$,and the cohomology purity can be proved by smooth base change, cohomology ring of$P^n_k$ can be calculated as well.

My question is：can we bulid up Poincare duality in this way?